# spriteBatch is Null

Tags: c#, xna, null, initialization, spritebatch

I'm creating a game and for the moment I have 3 classes, greenpaddle, ball, and Game1.

When i run my game, the debugger hops down to my `spriteBatch.Begin();`
and says **NullReferenceException Unhandled**.
This is my Game1.cs:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{

    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Ball ball;
    GreenPaddle gPaddle;
    Texture2D BackGround;


    public Game1()
    {

        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 500;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        gPaddle = new GreenPaddle();
        ball = new Ball(gPaddle);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        BackGround = Content.Load<Texture2D>("pongBG");
        gPaddle.LoadContent(Content);
        ball.LoadContent(Content);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        gPaddle.Update(gameTime);//Error Line
        ball.Update(gameTime);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();//Error Line
        spriteBatch.Draw(BackGround, new Vector2(0f, 0f), Color.White);
        gPaddle.Draw(spriteBatch);
        ball.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Don't know what's wrong, this have never happened to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you initialized spritebatch...

`spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);`

...It shouldn't be `null` unless one of your other classes is changing it.

**Things you can try:**

-Put a breakpoint on it in load content, I don't know why it wouldn't be called, but just check in case, make sure that `LoadContent()` is being called.

-Rebuild you project and make sure your changes are being saved.

---

...As I was writing this answer and testing the code on my machine I finally found the error. I'll leave the advice above in case anyone else has one of those issues.

You are not calling `base.Initialize` in your `Initialize()` method. This method calls the internal XNA stuff, which results in your `LoadContent()` being called.

It is also a good idea to call `base.LoadContent` in the `LoadContent()` method, you should always call the base method on any overridden method.